# android notification expanded view with more than 1 process bar

Tags: android, notifications

I want to my app that can download multiple files  simultaneously and show process of download each file in the notification area 
How can I do this?Now I can show only 1 process bar when I download files. 
Here file notification_progress_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dp">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/status_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_download1"/>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/status_icon">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/status_text" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        />
    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/status_progress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/status_text"
        android:indeterminate="false" 
        android:indeterminateOnly="false"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"  />


</RelativeLayout>
```

and nofitication file

```
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon_download1, "Downloading...", System.currentTimeMillis());

        contentView = new RemoteViews(activity.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_progress_layout);
        contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, 100, 0, false);        
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.status_text,"Downloading...");  

        notification.flags = notification.flags| Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        notification.contentView = contentView;         
        notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,notification);
```

Comment: I think it only makes sense for the expendable notifications introduced in 4.1. Search BigContentView to get a couple of samples on how to do implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this:

1. create a default XML with a `LinearLayout` inside.
2. create another layout with a `ProgressBar` inside.
3. use the following code.

Code:

```
contentView = new RemoteViews(activity.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_progress_main);
for (i=0; i<downloads.length;i++){
   contentView2 = new RemoteViews(activity.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_progress_layout);
   contentView2.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, 100, 0, false); 
   contentView.addView(R.layout.linearid, contentView2);

}
notification.contentView = contentView;
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,notification);
```

Change progressBar values with correct values for each downloads.

Comment: If I do that then I have different notifications and each notification has one process bar.Is it possible if I put multiple process bar in one notification?

Comment: Thanks, when download completed ,I want to remove each process bar.I see RemoteView doesn't have remove child layout function.How can I do this

Comment: When download is complete just remove it from downloads array like this you don't make "addView" so it's not on your final remoteView do you understand ?

Comment: you don't make "addView"  it's not on your final remoteView ??? Can you explain more

Comment: Every time you update your notification you refresh ALL notification's view cause you can't only change one part of the view. So each time you update your view you put 3 downloads for example so you have 3 progressBar and 3 addView. One is finish so you don't want to see it you just have now 2 downloads and 2 addView. You don't need to remove a view just don't add it when you make an update on your notification cause all view is replace. Sorry for my english i hope it's more clear or ask me more questions